# css testing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using controller to change the class of an object in angularjs

```
$scope.$watch('sideQuery',function(){
        if($scope.sideQuery==""){
            $(".indicator").removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
            $(".indicator").addClass('glyphicon-plus');

        }
        else{
            $(".indicator").removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
            $(".indicator").addClass('glyphicon-minus');

        }
    });
```

How to test using karma? a function like

```
expect(scope.elem('.indicator').hasClass("glyphicon-plus")).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, do not use jQuery to toggle classes in Angular, it defeats the purpose of it. Use `ng-class` and apply your classes based on flags, like so:

```
<div class="indicator" ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus' : sideQuery != '', 'glyphicon-plus':sideQuery == ''} ></div>
```

Then in testing check the value of `sideQuery` and know that you'll have classes based off that.

Comment: Thanks! :-)
How to test whether the element has that class('glyphicon-plus') or not?

Comment: Dont test the element, test that scope variable, if it's empty, it has that class `plus` - else `minus`

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing a directive, then you can compile a sample element and test the result object.

```
var $element;
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile) {
    $element = $compile('<div data-my-directive></div>')($scope);
}));

it('should have the class "someClass"', function(){
    expect($element.hasClass('someClass')).toBe(true);
});
```

However, be aware that tymeJV is right, you should use the `ng-class` directive and test your scope's values. If the scope value is right, then the class will be applied (you don't have to test the `ng-class` directive, that's something done in Angular's unit tests).

Comment: I am testing in controller and it is showing ReferenceError: $compile is not defined

Comment: You will need to inject the $compile service in

Comment: @Stranger, you shouldn't use jQuery in a controller, that's something that should be done in a directive. As for the $compile variable, it must be injected in the function where you are going to use it (I've just updated the code).

Comment: sorry for irritating you.
It is showing....
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile) {
        $element = $compile('<div data-my-directive></div>')(scope);
    }));
TypeError: undefined is not a function
     at null.<anonymous>
TypeError: scope.$element is not a function

Comment: @Stranger, no problem, it's kinda difficult to write code here in comments, take a look at [this example of a directive's unit testing](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/blob/master/test/tabsSpec.js#L10-L27). scope.$element doesn't exist... $element is a variable defined inside your test.